# wpf comboBox set selectedindex -1 but still show previous text

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

First, i select one item on the comboBox when the application is running.

Then i make some operations and after that i set the comboBox's selectedIndex -1 in the code. Actually, the comboBox's selectedItem is null now but it still displays the previous text on the UI. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You Should use:**

> comboBox.Items.Clear();

**Explanation**

> It is a **Bad** practice setting your comboBox to a `null` selected Item. You should always (if possible) try to use microsoft standard functionality for these kind of actions.
> It is more readable in this matter and safer to use.